# Multiple RewriteCond doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have in htaccess some like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-z]{2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/en [L,R=301]
```

I want redirect if non-www and non-lang

What is wrong?

Comment: Doesn't work how? What happens? It causes an earthquake? Your cat starts cleaning up after itself? You receive an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need a `OR` instead of default `AND`.

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2}/)?(.*)$ https://www.%1/en$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anubhava, your reply has helped me to find the final answer to my case.

I finally solved using this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2})?(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/en [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, it won't redirect `http://www.example.com/about` to `http://www.example.com/en/about`